# checking JSON data with jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I have written a php script:

**cch.php**:

```
$stmtcheck = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,email,location FROM members WHERE email=? AND unlock_code=?");
$stmtcheck->bind_param("si", $_SESSION['unlockemail'], $_POST['code']);
$stmtcheck->execute();
$stmtcheck->bind_result($id,$email,$location);
$stmtcheck->fetch();
         $array=array($id,$email,$location);    
        json_encode($array);
$stmtcheck->close();
```

And jquery for submitting form is

**recover.php**:

```
$("#formUnlock").submit(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();

   $.ajax(
   {
        url: '../scripts/cch.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $(#formUnlock).serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function()
        {

        }
   }); 
});
```

The script is returning more than one variable and the returned data should be in JSON format.

How do I read the data in jQuery?

Comment: you need to echo the json on the PHP side, the response is returned to the success callback function in JS.

Comment: `echo json_encode($array);`

Comment: Same question as here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40572547/checking-returned-data-from-php-script-through-jquery/40572629?noredirect=1#comment68381026_40572629 -You can edit question there itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $("#formUnlock").submit(function(e)
    {
       e.preventDefault();

       $.ajax(
       {
            url: '../scripts/cch.php',
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(#formUnlock).serialize(),
            dataType: 'JSON',
            success: function(data) //parameter missing
            {
    var json = $.parseJSON(data);
console.log(json);
//in console you will get the result response        
            }
       }); 
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Hello your php code should echo the JSON output like this:

```
<?php
$stmtcheck = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT id,email,location FROM members WHERE email=? AND unlock_code=?");
$stmtcheck->bind_param("si", $_SESSION['unlockemail'], $_POST['code']);
$stmtcheck->execute();
$stmtcheck->bind_result($id,$email,$location);
$stmtcheck->fetch();
$array=array($id,$email,$location);
$stmtcheck->close();
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

Now, in your javascript, you can use JSON.parse method to get the JSON.
Also, specifying your response type as JSON will automatically return a JSON object.

```
$("#formUnlock").submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '../scripts/cch.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: $('#formUnlock').serialize(),
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (json_string) {
            var res = JSON.parse(json_string);
            console.log(res);//This should output your JSON in console..
        }
    });
});
```